# How to remove numbering from "lynx --dump -listonly"

Tags: bash, url, formatting, sh, lynx

```
$ lynx --dump -listonly index.html
```

Example result:

```
References

Visible links
1. http://lynx.invisible-island.net/
2. http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx.html
3. http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/index.html
```

What I want to do is remove the 1. 2. and 3. "References" and "Visible Links" text included.

Wanted Result:

```
http://lynx.invisible-island.net/
http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx.html
http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/index.html
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post them even if they are trivial

Comment: You can pipe it to `sed` to remove the initial digits.

Comment: sed, awk, and grep all confuse me, I've already solved this problem, but it involves pasting the index.html to https://www.browserling.com/tools/extract-urls . I'm gonna have to do this in the future, and would like to put this into a nice single script.

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian I think you mean that regular expressions confuse you.

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian: Suggest following a good tutorial to learn how to use them if you are planning to work with them. For now you could pipe the output to `sed` as  `lynx .. |  sed -n 's/^[[:digit:]]\.[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\1/p'` or for numbers greater than one digit do `sed -n 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\)\.[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\2/p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
lynx --dump -listonly index.html | sed -r 's/^[0-9]+\. //'
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use **-nonumbers** option of Lynx

```
lynx --dump -nonumbers -listonly http://lynx.invisible-island.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this **input**, with spaces on top of each line:

```
 1. http://lynx.invisible-island.net/
 2. http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx.html
```

then, with the suppression of lines 1 to 3:

```
lynx --dump -listonly http://lynx.invisible-island.net/ | sed -E 's/^ ?+[0-9]+\. //; 1,3d'
```

**output**

```
http://lynx.invisible-island.net/
http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx.html
```